# Date Format in Python with offset and hours and minutes

Tags: python, date, avro

I have Date as below in csv file, which i want to load into avro file with same format,

Date Values:

```
2020-01-29 21:08:53.0041 +00:00
```

Format i tried to convert is as below:

```
%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f +%h:%m
```

which loads as null in avro file.

Schema i mentioned in avro is as below:

```
{
                "name": "requestdate",
                "type": [
                    "null",
                    "long"
                ],
                "default": null,
                "logicalType": "timestamp-millis",
                "doc": "requestdate"
```

Can someone help me on loading correct format

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime` `strptime` method. However timezone field is not valid, so you should remove semi colon of it. You can use regex to fix timezone field.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import re

# example
dt = '2020-01-29 21:08:53.0041 +00:00'

# remove semicolon in timezone field
dt = re.sub(r"([+-]\d+):(\d+)$", r"\1\2", dt)

# parse
value = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z')

print(value)
```

Output

```
2020-01-29 21:08:53.004100+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z

Comment: Nope, It is not working. might be due to avro conversion(as i mentioned logical type as "timestamp-millis")?